# Entityframework subclass does not contain it's properties upon enumerating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

Using an easy example:

I have a class **Car**, with subclass **Mazda**.

**Mazda** has a property: **MazdaWarrentyDate**

Using my Db Context, I go:

```
var collection = db.user.cars;
```

I then, loop through collectiong using: `var c in collection`

I use a conditional to check if the type of instance is a mazda and then cast it to a mazda.
But the **MazdaWarrentyDate is null!**

Upon debugging, I looked at the POCO before casting it, and indeed this property is not present, even though it recognised it as a type Mazda.

**Is this a limitation in Entity framework?** If so, how can I get around this? Thank you!

Comment: read about TPT: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

Comment: Thanks Luke, I will review other options at the moment, as I don't want to go down such a path right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the associate object was null, was because I started by querying at
user -> car etc.
To fix it, I simply started by querying at cars, e.g:

```
db.cars.where(c => c.user.id == myUserId);
```

Doing this caused the related poco's to be lazy loaded and this can all be iterated in one loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
var collection = db.user.cars.Where(t=> t is Mazda).OfType<Mazda>();

foreach (var car in collection ){

    //TODO 

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to also process other subtypes in one iterator though, is that possible?

Comment: I dont think this will solve his problem unless his DBcontext lists the dbset as mazda or a subtype of that

Comment: You can create a template method and then iterate over it.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor he does not have to.

Comment: I think @kkocabiyik is correct. Also no my context only contains the superclass.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that it wasn't a property but an associated object. Looks like by marking it as virtual, and using @kkocabiyik method, It's working. However It'd like the option to iterate once, over all subtyped.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz if your context only contains the superclass what is the generated table structure going to look like?

Comment: There is a discriminator column

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Entity Framework organizes subclasses on-the-fly to the same table, discriminating with Discriminator column

Comment: Looks like it was caused by another issue, thanks for the help guys. I've added an answer below.